# Qt: Hover is not working after opening external link on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, qml, macos-high-sierra

This reproduces for QML and QWidget's, but my example is in QML.

So here is an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "gold"

    ListView {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height / 2 * 3
        model: 5
        spacing: 1
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            color: ma.containsMouse ? "mediumvioletred" : "mintcream"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Click on me to open google.com"
                font.bold: true
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: ma
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: Qt.openUrlExternally("https://www.google.com/");
                hoverEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        width: parent.width
        height: 200
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        color: "black"
        text: "1. Click on any list element (note color when hovered)\n2. Re-gain focus by click outside of the list (gold color area)\n3. Hover list element";
        font.bold: true
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

Do the following:

1. Click on the list element to open external link in the browser
2. Go back to the example app and click **outside** of a list (gold area)
3. Immediately after this, try to hover list element

Result - hover stops working for some time.

Again, it reproduces the same if is written with QWidget.
My OS is **MacOS 10.12.6**

Is it a bug or something that can be fixed?

Comment: It seems it's a Qt bug. I've created the bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its a bug! also, its not observed on both Windows and Linux.

In MacOS newly open apps "**steal mouse focus**" from your running app; also  **"focus does not follow mouse behavior!"** this is extensively discussed in the blog [Settling the OS X focus-follows-mouse debate](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/04/settling-osx-focus-follows-mouse-debate.html)

By the way, regarding your observation  .. namely (hover stops working for *some time* after pressing inside gold area) .. you might have just been tricked, because what I noticed is that hover never restored until either:

- Press inside window (gold area) to bring it to foreground, then hover **outside** your window and back to regain mouse focus. or,
- Directly bring window and focus to foreground by pressing on window bar.

Again another  blog [Keep applications from stealing focus when opening in OS X](https://www.cnet.com/news/keep-applications-from-stealing-focus-when-opening-in-os-x/) confirms the issue and proposes some *weak* workarounds, for example to start child apps in *background* in different ways, but I don't think this is a choice for you because you don't want to modify the `Info.plist` for your browser.

what I could do is to *kill* the issue by bringing the window back to foreground (`hide()` and `show()` again), which seems to work and bring back stolen mouse focus, I agree this does not sound like a solution but it rather confirms the concept of Mac behavior and that its not a bug,
You can watch this by adding a mouse area to the golden area:

```
Text {
    width: parent.width
    height: 200
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    color: "black"
    text: "1. Click on any list element (note color when hovered)\n2. Re-gain focus by click outside of the list (gold color area)\n3. Hover list element";
    font.bold: true
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rootWindow.hide()
            rootWindow.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you press inside the golden area hover works like before.

Note: the `preventStealing :` property of `mousearea` does not seem to help because the mouse focus went outside your app, while this property works within elements of your app.

Comment: Well, I can't believe macOS is that stupid. User brought app to the foreground and then the app MUST have the mouse focus. How can this be that it still does not have it and it's not a bug? Rofl.

Comment: I don't think it's macOS "behavior". It seems it's a Qt bug. I do not see this behavior in non-Qt application under macOS.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev , been a while since this was checked. I remember the linked references confirm the behavior on mac, Could you check .. may be I missed something